# In which cases should hook_process() and hook_process_HOOK() be used?

Tags: theming, hooks

Considering that some modules implement [hook_process()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--theme.api.php/function/hook_process/7) to alter the content of some variables and replace their content with themed content, in which cases should a module implement `hook_process()` instead of [hook_preprocess()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess/7) (or [hook_preprocess_HOOK()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--theme.api.php/function/hook_preprocess_HOOK/7))?

```
function rdf_process(&$variables, $hook) {
  // Handles attributes needed for content not covered by title, content,
  // and field items. It does this by adjusting the variable sent to the
  // template so that the template doesn't have to worry about it. See
  // theme_rdf_template_variable_wrapper().
  if (!empty($variables['rdf_template_variable_attributes_array'])) {
    foreach ($variables['rdf_template_variable_attributes_array'] as $variable_name => $attributes) {
      $context = array(
        'hook' => $hook, 
        'variable_name' => $variable_name, 
        'variables' => $variables,
      );
      $variables[$variable_name] = theme('rdf_template_variable_wrapper', array('content' => $variables[$variable_name], 'attributes' => $attributes, 'context' => $context));
    }
  }
  // Handles additional attributes about a template entity that for RDF parsing
  // reasons, can't be placed into that template's $attributes variable. This
  // is "meta" information that is related to particular content, so render it
  // close to that content.
  if (!empty($variables['rdf_metadata_attributes_array'])) {
    if (!isset($variables['content']['#prefix'])) {
      $variables['content']['#prefix'] = '';
    }
    $variables['content']['#prefix'] = theme('rdf_metadata', array('metadata' => $variables['rdf_metadata_attributes_array'])) . $variables['content']['#prefix'];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll try to stay away from explaining the whole theme system. The order and use of the functions is best explained [here](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--theme.inc/function/theme).

Preprocessor functions run before process functions. You should run hook process for cases where you want to affect every theme call after all the preprocessors have run. (Well, I believe it is only every theme call with a .tpl file.)

RDF is a good example as it wants to insert meta data into every theme template. But in most cases it is not something you would want to do. Another example would be something like the [Pirate](http://drupal.org/project/pirate) module.

Preprocessors are more targeted. If you only want to change lists for example you could use a preprocess hook there. I believe that `hook_preprocess_HOOK()`s are run for templates and functions.

`hook_preprocess()` can be used in a theme if you wish to preprocess something which is not overridden in your theme, as the `theme_preprocess_HOOK()` won't trigger unless you do.

Comment: All correct except that in D7, preprocess/process functions are called for theme functions too, not only templates.

Comment: Are you sure? The docs say otherwise "If the implementation is a function, only the theme-hook-specific preprocess and process functions (the ones ending in _HOOK) are called from the list above."

Comment: Oh, that is possible, yes. I misread that in your answer.